# XML element values restricted by other element values

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to create a XSD schema and I'm not sure how to achieve one functionality (or even if it's possible at all).
Basically let say I have the following XML:

```
<root>
<allowedElements>
    <element name="a"/>
    <element name="b" />
</allowedElements>

<someList>
    <listEntry elementA="has to be value from allowedElements"/>
</someList>
```

Is it possible (and if so, how) to write the XSD schema in such a way that the 'elementA' attribute from 'listEntry' element would have to have value specified in the  element? I.e.

This XML:

```
<root>
<allowedElements>
    <element name="a"/>
    <element name="b" />
</allowedElements>

<someList>
    <listEntry elementA="b"/>
</someList>
```

Would validate, but the one below would/should throw invalid value exception:

```
<root>
<allowedElements>
    <element name="a"/>
    <element name="b" />
</allowedElements>

<someList>
    <listEntry elementA="XYZ"/>
</someList>
```